# Swtor class questing help

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

I am about 4 levels lower than I should be. I keep dying and can't find a quest that's the same or lower level than me. I'm a level 8 consular on a level 12 consular class quest. Nothing has seemed to help me so I decided to ask.

Answer (score 3):

Don't do just the class quests, do the planet quests as well.  If you've done them all and are still underleveled — you shouldn't be — then you'll have to group with others or simply kill mobs for XP.  Make sure you are gearing up and learning your new moves as well, and learning how to use them.

You could also go back to the starter planet and quest/kill there, since you shouldn't have left it till level 10.